# QTableWidgetItem displays three dots instead of full text

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm using a QTableWidget with four column witch i programaticaly fill with QTableWidgetItem in a loop. it's working but the full text is not displaying, it show three dots instead like there isn't enough space:
[image: QTableWidgetItem show 3 dots]

if i double click on a row it will display the whole text:

[image: QTableWidgetItem display full text on edit]

**How to set QTableWidgetItem programatically to fill all available space, or disable the 3 dots system and just display the whole text event if it will overflow ?**

Here my simplified code that just fill the second problematic column:

```
    vector<OperationLine> lines = db->getOperationLines(ui->dateEditFrom->date(),ui->dateEditTo->date());

    ui->operationTableWidget->setRowCount(lines.size());
    ui->operationTableWidget->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideNone);

    for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){

        QTableWidgetItem* libelle_item = new QTableWidgetItem(lines.at(i).libelle);
        libelle_item->setToolTip(lines.at(i).libelle);
        setDocumentMode(libelle_item);
        libelle_item->setSizeHint(QSize(500,50));// <-does not seem to work
        ui->operationTableWidget->setItem(i,1,libelle_item);
    }

    ui->operationTableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

ps: OperationLine is a simple class and .libelle is just a QString. Manualy resizing the column does not help. I also tried to disable editing and it does not help either. However if i comment my loop and manualy add item with QtCreator it seem to work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually add item with Qt Creator"? While running the app under Qt Creator? In the Qt Creator Design view?

Comment: Anyway, if you mean adding in Qt Designer, check out the generated file `ui_something.h` file in your build dir. It will contain the actual code which does the insertion (you can go there by F2 or ctrl-click from that `ui->operationTableWidget` most easily, I think).

Comment: @hyde not while the app is running. it's while editing the .ui file under Qt Creator and then right click on the QTablewidget and chose edit items and i can manually add rows here, before compiling and runing the app.

Comment: I googled a while as I had the feeling there must be a simple solution - something with "text" and "elide" or "ellipses" in the function name... And then I found this answer: [How to prevent too aggressive text elide in QTableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210373/7478597) and another similar [How can I create a QTableWidgetItem right-justified with long text, with the ellipses on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191593/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat actualy the solution proposed in your post did work ! and in the mean time it make me realize that my text contain return line \n and that why i was having 3 dots where the return line is, and why just typing the text in Qt Creator(whithout return line) worked. In the end with my original code i just have to remove return line in my strings. Thanks you for pointing that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original string contain return lines, removing them like:

```
QString s = lines.at(i).libelle;
s.replace('\n',' ');
ui->operationTableWidget->setItem(i,1,s);
```

is working.

As @Scheff'sCat pointed out in the comment of my original post, using the accepted solution at [How to prevent too aggressive text elide in QTableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210373/7478597) work too and will display multiple lines withouts the dots in the wrong place.