# Strange behavior of QTableView with text containing slashes

Tags: c++, qt, text

We recently ported a project from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.15 (Qt 6 isn't an option for us yet due to dependencies).

We're finding that all our QTableViews behave strangely when an item's text contains slashes.
Here is a small program that demonstrates 2 issues:

```
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget tbl;
    tbl.setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideLeft);
    tbl.setColumnCount(2);
    tbl.setRowCount(argc-1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        tbl.setItem( i-1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)) );
        tbl.setItem( i-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(argv[i]) );
    }
    tbl.show();
    
    auto* pModel = tbl.model();
    QString qstrMatch = "*single*file*";
    QModelIndexList lst = pModel->match(pModel->index(0,1), Qt::DisplayRole, qstrMatch, -1, Qt::MatchWildcard);
    qDebug() << lst.size() << "results";
    for (const QModelIndex& idx : lst)
    {
        qDebug() << argv[1+idx.row()];
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Suppose we run this program with the following 4 strings:

```
/path/to/design/patterns/singleton_file.txt
/path/to/design/patterns/observer_file.txt
just_single_name_file_no_path.txt
drill a single 1/4 inch hole then file here
```

##### 1) Text elision

In Qt 4, the `Qt::ElideLeft` is honored in all cases:

[image]

But in Qt 5, it seems to have a problem whenever the text contains a slash:

[image]

A colleague noticed that one table was still working as expected, and found that the thing it did differently was to use a custom delegate.
Sure enough, simply doing `tbl.setItemDelegate(new QItemDelegate)` on other tables fixes the issue for them as well.
But this doesn't seem to make any sense.

##### 2) Text matching

In Qt 4, the call to the `match` function does return 3 results as expected.
In Qt 5, it only returns only 1 result - for the string not containing a slash.

Implementing the search with our own loop by using a `QRegExp` with `Wildcard` syntax works as expected, though.

---

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/sourcebreaks.html does not provide any pointers as to what might have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to find the reasons behind and solutions for these issues after some digging in Qt 5's source code.

The two issues are unrelated.

##### 1) Text elision

After studying the Qt source code for a while, I stumbled on this doc comment for `QTableView::setWordWrap`:

> Note that even of wrapping is enabled, the cell will not be expanded to fit all text. Ellipsis will be inserted according to the current textElideMode.

Word wrapping is on by default, and its effect becomes clear only when you manually resize the row:

[image]

So the "..." is not for "horizontal" text width elision but for "vertical" word wrapped truncation.
The solution is to simply use: `setWordWrap(false)` on the `QTableView`.

The reason that using `QItemDelegate` made a difference appears to be that its implementation does simple elision *before* word wrapping, whereas `QStyledItemDelegate` (the default) first wraps and *then* only elides lines having very long words that could not be wrapped.
(It's not clear which part of this was done differently in Qt 4: Possibly slashes were not considered as valid word boundaries for wrapping.)

##### 2) Text matching

The underlying difference is in the `QAbstractItemModel::match` function: using a `QRegExp` with `Wildcard` syntax earlier vs. `QRegularExpression::wildcardToRegularExpression` now.
As the documentation of the latter function states:

> The transformation is targeting file path globbing, which means in particular that path separators receive special treatment.

This means that the text of every item is treated as a file path, where each `*` can match only within one single path component - it cannot span across slashes (it translates to something like `[^/]*` not just `.*`). So the wildcard pattern would need to have a particular number of slashes and stars in order to match the text.

So the only solution (if we choose to use `QAbstractItemModel::match` instead of rolling our own loops) appears to be to write our own `wildcardToRegularExpression` implementation that doesn't assume that the wildcards are being used for file paths, and hence does not treat path separators specially, and then use the `Qt::RegularExpression` match flag. Such a function would also be needed in other places where use of the now deprecated `QRegExp` with `Wildcard` syntax needs to be replaced with `QRegularExpression`.

Comment: I had a program that mysteriously started doing that ages ago when I upgraded, and only now got around to fixing.  This would have taken me a long time to figure out, or to do some ugly changing the contents of strings as the table is resized.